# How to directly invoke AWS Lambda function from an Android app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke one AWS Lambda function from my Android application.
If I understand correctly, I have to start with something like this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyId, secret);
AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
            .withRegion(regionName);

AWSLambda lambdaClient = builder.build();
```

and then the rest of the code with InvokeRequest etc.

Problem is in the above code, after it app crashes. I can't find the correct set of libs to make this work in Android.
If I use

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.782'
```

then it compiles fine and executes up to the "builder.build()" and then crashes and if I use

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.16.12'
```

(which is supposed to be used for Android???) Then "import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;" is red cause there's no such thing in the lib..

I get that AWSLambdaClient is deprecated and AWSLambda should be used, then what about AWSLambdaClientBuilder? What should I use?

Basically, if everything above is wrong, how do I get to call AWS Lambda function (by the way, this is without using API Gateway) from an Android app? What libs (with versions) would work for it?

I tried to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-android-example.html tutorial, but they also have deprecated stuff, plus it wants to involve Cognito and I was under the impression that I could call a function directly with a key and secret of a user with specific policy..

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, but you can use the API gateway or application load balancer and call the configured endpoint from the android application. 
Benefit with this, you will not need to configure the application to have the client id, and client secret set up, and even if restart, it would be simple api gateway call.

Lambda can work with both API Gateway as well as Application Load Balancer, and it is pretty easy to configure. [Refer this page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/) for details on ALB with Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'm not familiar with ALB method of using Lambda, so I'll go read the article, but as for the API Gateway (which I did use in the past), here the whole idea was to try to avoid using it.

Comment: I can not use Function URL or API gateway because in that case I get error "414 URL Too Long".

Comment: @shantanuo I not gonna fight for bounty probably, but you **can** use lambda URL. If you get "URL too long", you're just doing something weird. If you need to pass parameters, use POST request and pass parameters as body, not as query parameters. After that you can make your url as short as lambda URL (using just `/` path), and lambda URL length is within any reasonable limit.

Comment: As you have correctly pointed out, that error is returned when I tried "GET" method. But can you show me an example where I can "POST" request through Function URL without using API gateway?